# Applescript Login Item for All Users

Tags: macos, applescript

Using `Applescript` how can I register a login item for all users?

I understand that there is a `library/preferences/loginwindow.plist` file which holds this information.

I need to launch safari on log in and navigate to a URL. This needs to be done for any user that logs in. I've been looking to Launch Agents and this seems like my best bet.

I have the following in `Library/LaunchAgents/` which is launching safari at log in but I don't know how to specifiy the URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>heymega.safari.launcher</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: `loginwindow.plist` holds the information about the version of `OS X`, however, `com.apple.loginwindow.plist` hooks login and logout scripts - which might be what you're asking. Specifically what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for your response, I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include the `url` as an argument:

```
<string>/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari</string>
<string>http://example.com</string>
```

If that doesn't work you could try calling `osascript` to direct `Safari` to the url:

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari & sleep 1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.example.com"'
```

The `osascript` method uses sleep so that Safari has a chance to launch before executing.